# Camera Pixels Android Studio

Tags: camera, android-camera

Can we display Camera pixels (both primary and secondary) in Android Studio? If yes, How to display?

```
CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
tvCamera.setText(String.valueOf(cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics()));
```

I left "getCameraCharacteristics()" blank. Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this source:
[Camera2Raw](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Raw)

Comment: Nope. That did not help.